# How to pass a value from a main activity to a sub activity using intent?

Tags: android, android-listview

I used a listview clist 
and used  clist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
Now i want to get the item which i clicked  on a sub activity which i called using an intent.
How can i do this????
Thanks in advance for those help me....

Answer (score 0):

clist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3)
        {
            String xy=clist.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            temp=xy.split("-");
                            String xz=temp[0]; 
                Intent intente=new Intent(Cardetails.this,EditPage.class);
                intente.putExtra("key",xz);
            startActivityForResult(intente, var2);  

        }

    });
```

var2 is the request code.